# Is there any similar command in DataGrip for Alt+F1 in SQL server management?

Tags: ssms, datagrip

In SQL Server Management Studio, I could select a table name then press Alt+F1, it will show the table schema.

Is there a similar command in DataGrip?

Comment: This is a question only relevant to datagrip not all the other tags in here.

Comment: I have modified the tags, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+F6 will let you get the details of the table. But make sure just cancel/close the window after reviewing :P